# как на языке 1С написать HTTP POST запрос с параметрами и basic auth

Tags: json, http, 1с

Есть вот такой метод на удаленном сервере, 
(`POST`): `/api/v1/value/new/<slot_id>` - присвоить новое значение

Надо передать единицу. JSON параметры выглядят так:

```
{"value":{ "value": 1, "value_id": "5a1a62501996da00f10bbbef" }}
```

Как то же самое написать на языке 1С (8.3) с авторизацией по имени пользователя и паролю?

Answer (score 2):

Примерно вот так

```
хСоединение =   Новый HTTPСоединение(АдресСервера,443,"логин","пароль",,,Новый ЗащищенноеСоединениеOpenSSL);
хЗапрос     =   Новый HTTPЗапрос;
хЗапрос.УстановитьТелоИзСтроки("ваша JSON строка");
хЗапрос.АдресРесурса    = "api/v1/value/new/";
Ответ       = хСоединение.ВызватьHTTPМетод("POST",хЗапрос);
```

Comment: 1С сам поймет что в теле лежит json и в HTTP запрос добавит заголовок `Content-Type: application/json`?

Comment: @gil9red, нет, заголовки пишутся отдельно через соответствия.
`Заголовки = Новый Соответствие;`
`Заголовки.Вставить("service-method","list");`
`хЗапрос.Заголовки = Заголовки;`

Comment: Понятно, спасибо за ответ )

Answer (score 1):

Если ещё актуально: http://helpme1c.ru/rabota-s-http-zaprosami-get-i-post-v-yazyke-1s-8-3-8-2-v-primerax

Нужны методы

> УстановитьТелоИзСтроки()

и

> ОтправитьДляОбработки()

Для авторизации тут простой http: логин и пароль соединяются через двоеточие, кодируются в base64 и устанавливаются как authorization: Basic + строка в Base64 в заголовке запроса https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication